# Phonegap application doesn't work on Windows phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have developed an app in apache cordova aka phonegap. My application is working on android and ios platform properly but does not work on windows phone 8. I am using latest version of phonegap framework(3.5). Console Output of Visual Studio 2013:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll ****>>>(OK)
Updating IsolatedStorage for APP:DeviceID :: 65253133-611e-4bfc-89d6-cf7924246d63 ****>>>(OK)
Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only.
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted 
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
Channel not fired: onNativeReady 
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady 
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
```

Please help me, I am frustrated.

Comment: Last line `DB Compatiblity Issue` is the key. Can you show or tell what you are trying to do with DB? WP8 has limited support for WEBSql and local storage.

Comment: This is working all fine in android and iPhone. The plugins, which I have used in this project is also available in windows phone also. I have check it.

Comment: Please Tell me which Database you are using in this project and which jquery Framework is using in this project?

Comment: I am using JQM 1.3 and web sql for database as provided by cordova.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, JQM 1.3 does not supports windows phone 8 or 8.1. It supports windows phone 7.5-7.8 as mentioned in its documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/1.3

I will suggest to upgrade your JQM framework to the latest version (currently 1.4 is available on their website). Your output error seems likely due to this J-Query Mobile framework compatibility issues and due to this, it does not fire the JQM events which you may have use in you code. Apache Cordova is successfully loading in you device by analyzing your console output. Deviceready, onNativeReady, onCordovaReady, onPluginsReady events fail due to the JQM and I bet that compiling your project in latest JQM framework version will solve this problem.

Secondly, Database compatibility issue is also there.  W3C Web SQL Database does not support the Windows Phone platform clearly stated in phonegap documentation. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html

You may also use IndexedDB for windows phone platform or any other which supports windows phone. Check availablity from: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

I hope so this will solve your issue.

Comment: One thing more "Updating IsolatedStorage for APP:DeviceID..." output in you console is possible due to this fact that you are using windows emulator for testing you app. Microsoft does not support the persistent storage in the windows phone emulator unlikely Android emulator. So try to use a real device for testing. It will properly test you database functionality.